# ASP.Net MVC2 - Registering a Route to Remove "Index"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I have a route that is working correctly in the form of the standard:

{controller}/{action}/{id}

Example real URL is:

**http: //mydomain/Project/Index/PRJ2010001**

I would like to remove the "Index" from the URL so that when a user enters:

**http: //mydomain/Project/PRJ2010001**

...the Index view is still rendered.

*Note that my ProjectID's always start with "PRJ"*

Questions:

1) How do I register this route in my Global.asax.cs file?

2) How would I generate the correct link (minus the "Index") in my views using Url.Action()?

This is what I tried:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "View Project",
            "Project/{id}",
            new { controller = "Project", action = "Index" },
            new { id = @"/^PRJ/" }      //regex constrains this route to only work if {id} begins with "PRJ"
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be with your regex. Try simply `"PRJ\w+"` or `"PRJ\d+"`

I'd even try it without the regex to make sure everything else works OK.

Comment: excellent: "PRJ\d{7}" did it (my ID's always start with PRJ and then go 7 digits beyond PRJ)

Answer (score 2):

MVC messes with your regex to make sure that the pattern matches the whole value rather than just part. Specifically, it does...

```
string pattern = "^(" + str + ")$";
return Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
                                     | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

so your regex is tested as `^(/^PRJ/)$`, which is nonsense. Passing in `"PRJ\\d+"` should work.

In this particular case I'd consider dropping the regex and just including PRJ in the URL pattern...

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "View Project",
        "Project/PRJ{id}",
        new { controller = "Project", action = "Index" }
    );
```

... though your action would then have to deal with receiving an ID without the prefix.